# perform segue to initial view from any view with Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, storyboard

I am developing an application using Storyboards. This application requires the user to be logged in.

The *Storyboard* has a Login View as initial. When login is ok, it performs a segue to a *TabViewController*.

On any call to the API, I check if the server returns 401 (not-authorized). If this happens, a boolean is set to false (boolean isLogged). AppDelegate observes this boolean. If value is changed to false, I want to return the user to the login screen (remember, the initial view on Storyboard).

Here is some code:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isLogged"]) {
    BOOL logged = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];
    if (logged) {
        NSLog(@"Logged in succesfully!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Logout performed");

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self.window layoutSubviews];

    }

}
```

This works fine, but when I try to login again *LoginOK* segue is not performed.

I have tried many other options, something like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *loginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];

[source presentModalViewController:loginController animated:YES];
```

But the problem is that I don't know which View Controller performed the logout. Source has to be the current View Controller shown in the application, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem changing the observer for *isLogged* from App Delegate to my custom *TabViewController*. In *viewDidLoad* I subscribe to this var.

In method *observeValueForKeyPath* I do the following:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

LoginViewController *loginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];


[self presentModalViewController:loginController animated:YES];
```

Comment: How do you dismiss your login view ? I get `Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <MyTabBarController: 0xc5735c0> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!` error :(

Comment: What I do now is replace rootViewController with loginViewController. So:  

    self.view.window.rootViewController = [self.view.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd share this rather random idea with you.

What if you didn't make the login screen an essential step in your view hierarchy, but **present it modally from any of your normal view controllers** as soon as app state needs logging in. That's what modal view controllers are there for - not letting the user resume the normal flow until some explicit prerequisite has been met.

By doing it this way you don't have to worry about unwinding the whole navigation stack to the initial controller. It's much easier to preserve the state as well, since as soon as the authentication is successfully performed user should be able to resume her normal workflow, not start over.

Just an idea.

**Update #1:**

One option is to use a custom notification to carry the *login is required* state. You'd have to make all your view controllers observe the notification and the one that is currently visible will perform the presenting of modal view controller.

You can use this code [borrowed from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777438/how-to-tell-if-uiviewcontrollers-view-is-visible) to check if a view controller instance is visible:

```
if (viewController.isViewLoaded && viewController.view.window) {
    // viewController is visible
}
```

Comment: Yes, maybe you're right, but it does not actually answers my question. How can I know from the AppDelegate which view is shown to call presentModalViewController method? Maybe is another way to do what I want.

Comment: I found a similar approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913840/login-screen-with-storyboarding-possible but I cannot figure what is source in this code.

Comment: I made an update (#1) to address your question in comment above.

Comment: This is a good idea.  In hindsight, I should've built my app with this structure