# How to perform a segue that is not related to user input in iOS 5?

Tags: ios5, storyboard

Consider a view with a button. We can drag a connection from this button to some other view controller, create a segue in IB and we are happy. What if I need a segue that is performed upon some event, say, network progress, and that is unrelated to any user actions? For now I'm placing a button, drag a segue from this button, hide the button, assign an identifier to a segue and somewhere in the code i perform this segue. However, I think that placing a dummy button is not a right way. Possibly I'm missing something using storyboards, could you please help me to understand this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Create your segue by ctrl dragging from your view controller to your next view.
Then to call your segue, call:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueToScene1" sender: self];`

Make sure you give your segue a name in the storyboard.

Comment: Ctrl-dragging from the view controller to the next view was the missing piece, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `performSegueWithIdentifier:` method to force the transition to a new `view`, based on some criteria.  When you call this, it will also automatically call `prepareForSegue:` (which is usually called when the `storyboard` is about to transition to a new `view`).

I wrote a post about controlling pushing `views` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object) which should cover most of what you're talking about.