# How to load UIViewController programmatically from storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift

I created a UIViewController in my Main.storyboard with a few buttons and labels. I'm trying to switch to that view controller using self.presentViewController but it will not load the view from storyboard. It will only load a blank black screen by default. Any idea on how to load the view from what i've created in storyboard?

```
self.presentViewController(ResultViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a View Controller programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134361/how-to-call-a-view-controller-programmatically)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The way you're doing this just creates a new instance of your view controller. It does not create one from the prototype you've defined in Interface Builder. Instead, you should be using this, where "SomeID" is a storyboard ID that you've assigned to your view controller in Interface Builder.

```
if let resultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SomeID") as? ResultViewController {
    presentViewController(resultController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You can assign a storyboard ID to your view controller in Interface Builder's identity inspector.

[image]

Comment: just a comment, you need to add a ! after storyboard in Swift 2

Answer (score 7):

Full Swift 3 code including instantiation of Storyboard:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

if let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() {
    present(mainViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: How do I do it on MacOS(Cocoa)?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**SWIFT 5.2**

first, you should define a storyboardID for viewcontroller and after use this code

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // type storyboard name instead of Main
 if let myViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myViewControllerID") as? CourseDetailVC {
       present(myViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```