# Opening viewController programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to open new UIViewController on the button through code. I have already made the controller in storyboard and just want to link it and also I don't want to use XIB interface or nibName?

Comment: The answer is right here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474115/how-to-load-uiviewcontroller-programmatically-from-storyboard

Comment: how to implement this if your viewcontroller has no storyboard

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To open New view controller you need to write this line in button click event:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoToViewController", sender:self)
```

To link up with new view controller follow this steps:

- Select New view controller from storyboard & right click on it
- You will find Dark dray popup will appear (see image )
- Now under Presenting Segues select Present Modally & drag to the View controller from where you need to open up this view controller & link it
- You will find new segue created under New view controller
- Now select that segue go to inspector & copy the identifier or rename & copy it
- Use that identifier in above line

Hope it will work.

[image]

Comment: Awesome solution

Comment: If i open new view controller in your way , will the previous view controller be destructed from memory ? @cyberlobe

Comment: how to implement this if your viewcontroller has no storyboard

Answer (score 14):

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("userProfileController") as UIViewController, animated: true)
```

I wanted to add my view controller to the navigation controller and this also worked

Comment: how to implement this if your viewcontroller has no storyboard

Answer (score 1):

For  swift 4.2, try the following code:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "inventoryViewController") as UIViewController, animated: true)
```