# OneSignal press push notification to go a view controller iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, onesignal

I want to navigate to a specific view controller after I pressed the push notification, how to do it in here with OneSignal Push notifications?

```
 _ = OneSignal(launchOptions: launchOptions, appId: "b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba") { (message, additionalData, isActive) in
        NSLog("OneSignal Notification opened:\nMessage: %@", message)

if additionalData != nil {
   NSLog("additionalData: %@", additionalData)
   // Check for and read any custom values you added to the notification
   // This done with the "Additonal Data" section the dashbaord.
   // OR setting the 'data' field on our REST API.
    if let customKey = additionalData["newid"] as! Int {
        //The navigation to a view controller code should be goes here...
        //I've no idea how to do it, I've tried some ways from stackoverflow also didn't work for me
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I believe this is general question about deep linking. Pl have look at [this](http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic-guides/ios-deep-linking.html) and [one more link](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-deep-linking-in-swift/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a segue like jkasten proposes, or also:

```
let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardID") as! ClassOfYourView
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Either way you will still need to create a storyboardID.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, one of them is to call this from your "newid" if statement.

```swift
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoToViewController", sender:self)
```

If the code above does not work I recommend trying a few other answers from [Opening viewController programatically in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441673/opening-viewcontroller-programatically-in-swift)

Comment: This code must have the segue identifier, I need to pass view in code instead of story board...