# how to keep current user session active using parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, usersession

I am attempting to keep the current user session active until the user decides to log out. What code i should i implement? and exactly where should it be implemented? the viewDidLoad, or viewWillAppear function of the root view? I have tried using this code in my root view:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let vc = ViewController()
        var loggedIn = false

        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
            loggedIn = true
        } else {
            presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

but whenever i stop the simulator and run it again, i have to log in all over again. What is the best solution? keep in my "ViewController" is my main view which holds my login/sign up fields. So i basically want a way to say if a current user session exist, continue, else, show initial view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your app delegate...

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

...

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

if (currentUser) {
  // there is a user logged in go to the main screen
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    MainViewController *mainViewController = (MainViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];

    //set the root controller to it
    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
} else {
// Log in!
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle: nil];
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = (LoginViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];

    //set the root controller to it
    self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
}

...
```

Comment: i tagged swift, not ob j.. if you can use swift syntax i can definitely try this

Comment: @MikeStrong I'm sorry for using objective-c, [this can help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474115/how-to-load-uiviewcontroller-programmatically-from-storyboard). Is simply load a view controller programmatically

Comment: This actually worked however it must be placed in the viewDidLoad function of the initial view not the app delegate. so if you adjust your answer i can accept it! thanks

Comment: @MikeStrong, The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html) refers to this: _Your app delegate is called to configure the initial view controller before it is displayed_, and in my case I use .xib for launch screen. I don't believe load of a vc for load other vc is efficient if exist a user session. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Parse is handling this for you when you register user properly with `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` (objective -c).

`PFUser.currentUser()` should be available all the time until you actively log out.

maybe you try to register -> fail -> go to next VC anyway -> start the app again without being actually registered ?

Comment: i dont understand your suggestion.

Comment: check the PFUser.currentUser() right after you register - to see that you get it when you "know" that are registered.

Answer (score 0):

Parse has provided developers with Sessions (for session management). for further help refer to Sessions Section in following link...
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide