# problem with .reloadData () when going between VC

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cocoapods

I try to use custom transition animation:https://github.com/AladinWay/TransitionButton

It works as it was intended, but for some reason, after switching to a new VC application, it stops. and displays the error `"Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"`

I successfully localized the problem to the line

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.collectionView.reloadData ()
                 }
```

without animation in the direct transition to VC problems arise. information is loaded and updated by reloading the view.

Perhaps the problem occurs during a direct transition to

```
 self.present (secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I tried to delete the self.collectionView.reloadData () line
then the error does not occur. It just remains a black screen.
But this is also a problem.

At first, I thought that the problem was with the pod, but I think that the problem is that there is a direct transition to the VC and the CollectionView just does not load, and when I try to upgrade, I get an error

```
import TransitionButton
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ button: TransitionButton) {
        button.startAnimation() // 2: Then start the animation when the user tap the button
        let qualityOfServiceClass = DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background
        let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: qualityOfServiceClass)
        backgroundQueue.async(execute: {

            sleep(3) // 3: Do your networking task or background work here.

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                // 4: Stop the animation, here you have three options for the `animationStyle` property:
                // .expand: useful when the task has been compeletd successfully and you want to expand the button and transit to another view controller in the completion callback
                // .shake: when you want to reflect to the user that the task did not complete successfly
                // .normal
                button.stopAnimation(animationStyle: .expand, completion: {
                    let secondVC = CarInfo()
                    self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            })
        })
    }
}

import TransitionButton
import UIKit

class CarInfo: CustomTransitionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var testSegue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        // create post request


                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }
        task.resume()
}
```

I plan to use this animation and in the background to load data from the API after displaying the finished page.
But now everything just breaks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474115/how-to-load-uiviewcontroller-programmatically-from-storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You should load this vc from storyboard so replace and set a storyboard identifier like `CardID`

```
let secondVC = CarInfo()
```

with

```
let secondVC  = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardID") as! CarInfo
```

Comment: It worked, but it didn't quite work out the way I intended.
How to save the binding to NavController
to be able to go back?

Comment: resolve 
need replace 

`self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

from

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "navSegue", sender: self)`

navSegue is identifier for segue which I have connected the two I need VC

Comment: your main problem which is the point of the question is loading the vc , using segue/present is your choice