# How to navigate programmatically to another viewcontroller with "over current context " presentation in ios 9, objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, storyboard

I'm building my app using storyboard.so I can open another view controller when button preesed,by dragging.and then I can select `presentation`= `over current context` for the segue in storyboard.But what I want is to do this programmatically.I found an answer,but it says it will work for only ipads.I'm building an universal app, so I want to work it for all devices.

- Is this possible.
- And how can I do that.

in my first view controller

```
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIViewController *middleViewController = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FlightMiddleViewController"];
```

and in my second view controller, viewDidLoad method I put

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
```

it works for a while.that means it transparent for while and then screen black.I don't know why is that.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16134703/3388012

Comment: thanx for the link.but it is not my case.I know how to `navigate` programmatically. what I want is how to set 'presentation' as `over current context`.anyway thanx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it is working for iphone also with ios 9 >=

this is what you want to do.

in your first view controller, before you set up which view should present,

```
- (IBAction)searchNowAction:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *secondViewController = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondviewControllerSBname"];


    secondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
    secondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

this works fine for iphones also.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set following property before presenting.

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
```

Also set definesPresentationContext property of parent controller to true

Yes it will work only for iPad, as modal presentations and popover controllers are only supported in iPad.

Comment: but if we do this using drag, then we can set it for iphones also.

Comment: when we test ,it is working(using drag and drop not ,programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not that hard to do `OverCurrentContext` presentation style on iPhone. Have a look at [UIViewController custom transition](http://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions), which was introduced in iOS 7. You will find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> For anyone that was doning `performSegue(..` programmatically

In my case I was having a `modal` that present a `button`. taping the button should push a new `viewController`, but it get push in `fullScreen` even if Im inside a `modal`

So after little search I found out that I was setting in `storyBoard` in xcode:
`Presentation => fullScreen`. So then I had to change is to `Current Context`