# Need help converting this bit of code from Swift to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have an Objective-C app where I need to load another VC class from within the code. I've managed to accomplish this in another Swift app.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OverrideClass")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I need help creating an identical function for ObjC. It's basically loading the class of the VC with the storyboard identifier mentioned in the code.

Comment: Any Objective-C tutorial will show you how the syntax for this works. The code is pretty much identical just with a different syntax.

Comment: Below link might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134703/5184217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is very similar just with a different syntax...

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL];
UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OverrideClass"];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code you provided re-written in Objective-C:

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL];
UIViewController * controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OverrideClass"];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```