# Printing vc1 NSString from vc2

Tags: iphone, storyboard

I want to print out vc1.string1 from vc2.

Currently console's showing:

> vc1.string1 (null)

When I was not using storyboard I accessed vc1 variable like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSLog(@"vc1.string1 %@", appDelegate.viewController.string1);
```

But I don't know how to access vc1.string when I'm using storyboard.

Help please thanks.

P.S.
Here's the link of my project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12439052/AccessDiffClass.zip

```
//ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString *string1;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string1;

@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize string1;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    string1 = @"String One";
    NSLog(@"string1 %@", string1);
}

@end
```

VC2:

```
//ViewController2.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController {
    ViewController *vc1;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *vc1;

@end

#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController2
@synthesize vc1;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"vc1.string1 %@", vc1.string1);
}

@end
```

Comment: why do you wanna use strong? usually we use retain

Comment: Yes I am using ARC. Is it harder or bad to work in that environment cause it's new? Or should I keep using it and going with the new feature.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Dautermann... well I am still used to managing memory by myself...

Comment: I thought managing memory manually would be more memory-efficient? Wrong?

Comment: @shader Yes, it is completely deterministic [About ARC](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/#myth-ARC-not-reliable)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your project and added this bit of code to your ViewController.m file:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog( @"preparing for segue" );
    ViewController2 * vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc2.vc1 = self;
}
```

And this got things appearing as you were hoping for in my simulator console.

Now, this is definitely **not** the best thing to do here.  In the ARC world, I don't know if vc1 is retained or if we're leaking or whatever.  It would be **much smarter** for you to give your ViewController2 class a `NSString *` property that gets set in the `prepareForSegue` method.  And also give an identifier to your segue.

[Here is another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object) that talks about `prepareForSegue` a bit more (and somewhat more detailed).

Comment: Ah actually this is not changing the value of string1 permanently. I want to access the string1 from vc2. Before I did that by accessing Appdelegate first then going to vc1.

Comment: Can you try with this project too please? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12439052/AccessWithoutAuto.zip

Comment: I was able to get your newer project to work merely by adding a `vc3.vc1 = self;` line in your `toVC3:` action method right after creating `vc3`. For something like this,  especially if you are using storyboards, I'd recommend just adding a `NSString` property to your application delegate and then set & read from that instead of trying to keep your string in one particular view controller (which disappears and can be released as soon as it finishes animating off the screen).

Comment: Thanks for keep replying http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12439052/NoStory.zip Here's one project where I make it work using ARC but without using storyboard. It's because there's some pre-written code in AppDelegate if I'm not using Storyboard. I tried @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController; & [[ViewController alloc]init] on using ARC+Storyboard project but the string1 would come out to be as null.

Comment: Hello SeungUn!  I've already looked at two projects and hope that I have helped you enough so that you can determine what the best course of action for your app will be.

Answer (score 0):

made a mistake last time try this.

Key Code:
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    vc1 = appDelegate.viewController;
    NSLog(@"string1 %@", vc1.string1);

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12439052/passingValue.zip