# Uiimageview on storyboard other segue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, storyboard

I have a segue with a uiimageview and 2 buttons to take a picture and choose one from the library. Then I want to go to the next segue and see this uiimageview there also.

So I need to send the image from the uiimageview to another segue om the storyboard.

Thanks in advanced,
Tim

Comment: What is the question you are asking?

Comment: How to show the image I picked on the next segue.

Answer (score 0):

Add an image property to the second view controller and set it in prepareForSegue:sender:.

There is a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object) that goes into this in some detail.