# Give NSString to other class on segue

Tags: objective-c, ios, class

In one class there is a list with all friends and their IDs. Now when you click on the item in the UITableView the Chat appears (`[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showChat" sender: self];`). But in the ChatViewController Class I need to access the variable userID from FirstViewController. I tried everything I found on the internet, but it always gives an error or the variable is empty.
In FirstViewController is a NSString `userid`, so how can I access this in ChatViewController.m? I tried to make the variable `@public`, I tried `@property` with readwrite and so on, but it doesn't work.
For example this:

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
userID = fvc.userID;
```

just gives an empty String..

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have `prepareForSegue:` method to pass the variable.

Implement the method as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showChat"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        ChatViewController *cvc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Set the object to the view controller here, like...
        cvc.userID = self.userID;
    }
}
```

You can find the [tutorial here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) on passing the value through segue.

**Update**

Similar question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

Answer (score 3):

You write this code in ChatViewController right . where u make a new instance of FirstViewController. 
And this is the problem new instance has userID always empty.

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
userID = fvc.userID;
```

U need to have ur old instance of FirstViewController or when u go FirstViewController to ChatViewController u have to pass this value to userID = fvc.userID;

```
    ChatViewController *cvc = [ChatViewController new];
    cvc.userID = self.userID;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
```

Bear in mind that u have set Property and synthesize the userID in ChatViewController.