# How to work with  "didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" method

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, appdelegate

MY PROBLEM: when the user a certain cell to select a player, I want the rest of the information related to that player to show up on the new view controller

So far my method looks like this:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
IPlayerViewController *detailViewController = [[IPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IPlayerViewController.h" bundle:nil];
Player *playerF = [playerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
detailViewController.PlayerLabel.text=playerF.Name;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

However the PlayerLabel that i created in IPlayerViewController (and connected the UILabel to the label in storyboard) is blank.

If this looks familiar it is because i am following the following tutorial, but trying to add my own things. Thanks a lot!
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

EDIT:
I am USING storyboard. However, in the predefined method, xcode came with the following comment to initialize with Nib Name which threw me off.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
   // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */

}
```

So it seems like I should use prepareForSegue. Is this something I call in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath or do i ignore that method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using storyboards, then most likely you won't see a call to `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. If you are using segues to get to the next view, then you will need to use `-prepareForSegue:sender:` see: [How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object).

---

**Update**

Do you have a segue from the table view cell to your detail view controller?

If you have a segue, then `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not what you want. If you have a segue, create a `-prepareForSegue:sender:` method in your table view controller. It will look something like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    Player *player = [self.playerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    IPlayerViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    destination.player = player;
}
```

Assuming of course that IPlayerViewController has a player property.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using storyboard and it has a call to:
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}

in this method would i still use:
    IPlayerViewController *detailViewController =[[IPlayerViewController alloc] prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboard Segue*) sender:id];

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thank you so much, I had been confused about the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for a while. I will have to research its exact uses more thoroughly. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I looked for :)

Answer (score 0):

In your next view controller.h you need a player property.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) Player *player;
```

If you are using storyboards, you will have to save the selectedRow index in your class, and implement the prepareForSegue method, like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

  NextViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController
  controller.player = [self.players objectAtIndex: YOUR_SAVED_INDEX];
}
```

Understood the concept?

Comment: I understand the concept, but can i implement prepareForSegue inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: no, prepare for segue will be called automatically if you link your tableview cell with your nextviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Since you're initing with a nib, I'll assume you're **not** using a storyboard....

I think you're doing everything right except, don't try to put the name directly into the label because it hasn't loaded yet.  Create a property in your detail controller that's just a string to hold the name.  Set **that** in your code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and then update the label in `viewDidLoad:` in the detail controller.

Comment: Thanks! I am using storyboard. I realized that I should not be initiating nib since im not using xib.