# Pass Data when using storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ios5 how to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

I love storyboards, but i cannot pass data from viewController1 to viewController2 using storyboards. I have researched, and found out a little about prepareForSegue. But im still lost! How can I simply pass a string from vc1 to vc2 when using prepare for segue? I have 1 button to switch views, and pass the string. Thanks in advance!

:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some tutorial for passing data between `ViewControllers` using `Storyboard`:

1. [Storyboards Segue Tutorial: Pass Data Between View Controllers](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)
2. [Tutorial on How-To Pass Data Between Two View Controllers](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-Tutorial-on-How-To-Pass-Data-Between-Two-View-Controllers)

or use something like this(just an example):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:...]) {
        MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        //What you are going to pass, for my example score as int
        controller.score = score;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.