# webview after checking user input

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.4

I'm a xcode noob, but here's what I'm looking for followed by what I've done. I've created a login and with that login usernameField I'm trying verify the user and open a only a web page specific to that person. The login is working here's all my code

```
//LoginViewController.h


    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @interface LoginViewController : UIViewController
    {
    IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
    IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;   
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *loginIndicator;
    }

    @property(nonatomic, strong) UITextField *usernameField;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) UITextField *passwordField;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton    *loginButton;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *loginIndicator;

    -(IBAction) login: (id) sender;
    @end


//LoginViewController.m


    #import "LoginViewController.h"
    @implementation LoginViewController
    @synthesize usernameField, passwordField, loginButton, loginIndicator;

    -(IBAction) login: (id) sender
    {
    if ([usernameField.text isEqualToString: @"userOne"] && [passwordField.text
    isEqualToString: @"passwordOne"])
    {
    printf("Success")
    //here is where I would like to pass usernameField.text to WebViews
    }
    else if (([usernameField.text isEqualToString: @"userTwo"] && [passwordField.text 
    isEqualToString: @"passwordTwo"])
    {
    printf("Success")
    //here is where I would like to pass usernameField.text to WebViews
    }
    else
    {
    printf("Login Failed")
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed"
                 message:@"Wrong username and password" delegate:self
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    }
    loginIndicator.hidden=False;
    [loginIndicator startAnimating];
    }
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"fromLogin"])
    {
        WebViews *wvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        wvc.usernamerField = self.usernameField.text;
    }
    }
    @end

//WebViews.h

    @interface WebViews : UIViewController
    {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    NSString *usernameField;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString*usernameField;

    @end

//WebViews.m

 #import "WebViews.h"
    @interface WebViews ()//To be honest I'm not sure what this is for
    @end
    @implementation WebViews
    @synthesize usernameField;

    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"username is = %@", self.usernameField);
    if([T.usernameField.text isEqualToString: @"userOne"])
    {
    [webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL 
    URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
    }
    else if([T.usernameField.text isEqualToString: @"userTwo"])
    {
    [webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"]]];
    }
    else
    {
    [webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wikipedia.com"]]];
    }

    @end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: BTW, you should do `[super viewDidLoad]` at the very start of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are never assigning anything to `T` so it is `nil` in your method.

In the code for your LoginViewController you need to pass the username to the WebViewController. You can do this by implementing the `prepareForSegue` method.

Here is an example, taken from [How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        WebViewController *wvc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        wvc.username = self.usernameField.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try logging when each function is getting called, and look at when wvc.username is getting assigned. Things are probably happening out of order.

Comment: You don't want any communication between the two views. When the second appears you want the first to be garbage collected.

Comment: Hey Nathan, I just wanted to thank you for all your help. This code does work, my problem was is that I was trying to have the login at the beginning of my program and then later access the information, now I'm not sure if I can have two segues but that's essentially what I'd need unless you know of away to access the information later in the program?

Comment: You should either store the username someplace global, or you could create a model object that you can pass from view to view. I'd probably chose the second route.

Comment: So I've created Users.h and Users.m; Users.h is simply `@interface Users: NSObject {NSString *username;} @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *username; @end`
Then in LoginViewController i do `Users*user = [[Users alloc] init];
user.username =@"userOne"` Now I believe I've created the object properly but is it global?

Comment: It is not. You would need to create a Users singleton. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like