# Adding another ViewController in Xcode IBAction control+drag and connect locks out .h and .m connections :-(

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xcode4.5, ibaction

I am using a storyboard in Xcode to build a pretty simple "contact information email to myself app" where a user will enter contact info then click a segway push that pops up an alert. Info from contact fields are dumped in text field on next viewController. This text field is then send with the click of a button on the next view controller.

My progress:

I can construct the first view controller and have the textfields and submit/segway push button with alert popup built and have that in another project.

In another project I have made the viewController with the textField and have it work to send me email with the push of email button. Email runs user pushes send and tadaaaa

My problems:

I try to add them together and it locks me out of IBAction/IBOutput contrl+drags in .h and .m

I want the content of this textView to come from five textfields of info on the previous view controller, so I am sure some IBOutput connections will need to be made and such.

I am looking for help and will post .h and .m upon request.

I am just having some difficulty finding out how to make the first textfields connect and dump info into the textView on the next viewController I can make email.

Comment: What view controllers do you have in your storyboard? Did you set the destination view's custom class to your view controller class?

Comment: They are standard "view controllers" first one in the list of objects

Comment: (I didnt mean to hit enter)    I did not set the " destination view's custom class to your view controller class?"   How would I go about doing so or what material do you suggest I look over to learn how to?

Comment: It's a little hard to decipher what exactly your question is. Read the ViewController docs http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW2 This is a good description of passing information between controllers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object

Comment: Awesome Help Jason! I guess simply put I want to create a Contact us page, then have the fields that are filled out be dumped into a textView in a separate view controller.   I am having a bit of trouble passing the data from one view to another. All the other features of the basic app I am after are there.  I appreciate your needed help and I am reading now.