# Pass plist Data from TableView in labels of another View

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, plist, segue

I try to make an app that shows Data from a plist in a `tableView` and when clicked pass that data to the `ViewController` using `prepareForSegue`.

I could set up the plist data appearing in the `tableViewCell` with `cell.textLabel.text`and `cell.detailTextLabel.text`. But until now, I was not able to get a working `Segue`.

How do I use `prepareForSegue` in order to pass over the Title and Subtitle of the `Cell` plus other Data that is located in the plist.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: you can `property` and `synthesize` any variable and have the access of that in your parent viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Use @property and @synthize for do it.

You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object) where there is a good explanation.