# iOS:passing data between two UITableViewController using storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard, uitableview

I'm working on iPad app using master-detail template were the master `tableview` is passing data to a second `tableviewController`:

Currently is what I have:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
    UITableViewController *secondTableView = [segue destinationViewController];
  }
```

My question is. Why when I try access a property in the `secondTableView` for example:

`secondTableView.myString = @"goodBye";`

I get this error:

> Property "myString" not found on object of type
>   "UTableViewController".

My question is how can I fix this or if is a way around this error.

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object/10858618#10858618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    UITableViewController *secondTableView = (UITableViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
```

And make sure `myString` should be declared as property.

Then you should try this

```
secondViewControllwer *secondView = (secondViewControllwer*)[[secondViewControllwer alloc]init];
```

And class name should start with capital latter.

Comment: Doesn't work because I still don't get any reference to my secondViewController. for example secondViewControllwer *secondView = [secondViewControllwer alloc]init] in that case I'm getting a pointer to the second class

Comment: @user3094099 what are you saying not cleared. What is your class name? If your class is `secondViewControllwer` then see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing undefined property on UITableViewController, moreover you cannot declare custom property on standard UITableViewController, you can only inject methods using category. I am wondering if UITableViewController is what you intended for secondTableView type?