# how to get access to view controller from another one?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

how to get a reference to some view controller in my app?, I do not need a new copy of the
view controller I just need a reference to that controller so I can use its methods and update its properties.

thanks

Comment: You can pass a reference to it to any View Controllers that need it, but ask yourself why you need to do this, maybe your design could be improved better?

Comment: how to get a ref for that view controller?!

Comment: You need to PASS it when you create the new View Controllers. E.g. [[YourViewController alloc] initWithOtherViewController:self]; Then store it, and reference it as you need it. It would help if you showed us some code, and what you have already?

Comment: I am in some view controller and I need a ref to another view controller which has a variables that must be updated from my current view controller any thing with ALLOC is wrong!

Comment: What references do you already have? Can you trace it back to your App Delegate?

Comment: I do not have any,I do not know how to create one!

Comment: So you want to update a progress bar?  Sounds like a good opportunity to create a protocol for a Delegate.

Comment: yes, because of that I need a ref to that view controller!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a parent-child relationship between the two?

If so, you might do something like

```
@interface ChildVC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) ParentVC *parent;

@end
```

and in the `ParentVC`:

```
- (void)methodThatShowsOrCreatesChildVC
{
    // ...
    ChildVC *childVC = [[ChildVC alloc] init];
    childVC.parent = self;
    // ...
}
```

In the `ChildVC`:

```
- (void)methodThatChangesSomethingOnParent
{
    [[self parent] changeSomethingOnParent:something];
}
```

---

If there is not a parent-child relationship, this sounds like unnecessary coupling. Rather than that, you could try:

- post a `NSNotification` about changes made
- have a shared `NSObject`-based class that contains the shared "concerns".

Comment: yes I want to get a ref for the parent view controller to update a progress bar in it from the child root controller!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation, if the viewController is visible or is in the memory, you can access it in an other class, by creating a property and then accessing its attributes (properties, methods).

Comment: I am using push and pop that means it is in the memory!

Comment: can you show an example of how to create a property?!

Comment: If  you are using storyboard and push/pop stack, access that as below:

UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard~IPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController * myStoryboardInitialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [myStoryboardInitialViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

else access the controller using

[self.navigationController.viewContrllers objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: your solution is creating new view controller and is not giving me a ref to the desired view controller

Answer (score 0):

When you push a new view controller with

```
performSegueWithIdentifier:
```

you'll get the delegate method

```
prepareForSegue:
```

Which passes a `UIStoryBoardSegue` that has properties `destinationViewController` and `sourceViewController`

and [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"])
    {
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `UINavigationController`, you can do this to get the `View Controller` at any index

```
UIViewController *targetViewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:([self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-1)];
```