# I lose my bluetooth connection after changing view on Ios

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I lose my bluetooth connection every time I try to change the `ViewController`

I put the `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` Methods in each `ViewController`.

How should I reorganize my code ?

Comment: do you mean ViewController ?

Comment: Yes, I can't change the ViewController without losing my connection

Comment: You should use a Singleton/SharedInstance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must `CBCentralManager` trough `ViewController`s on `PrepareForSegue` method so it will retain the instance

create new class for implement `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` and create its instance and pass it

you can use prepare for segue method accordingly this sample

[How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

Comment: I am not using a UITableViewController, why should I use a prepare for segue ?

Comment: you should use it to pass instances trough ViewControllers prepare for segue is not for just UITableViewController it can be used for every ViewController

Comment: Thank you, I know how to pass the title with 
 selector.title = @"LoopBack";  But not my CBPeripheralManagerDelegate, How can I do ?

Comment: It works but the "didReceiveWriteRequests" Method does work only with the old view, not with the new one