# XCODE: 2 viewcontroller connecting with one segue and 2 Uilabels data

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I have 2 viewcontroller connecting with one segue and 2 Uilabels with the same name in the Viewcontroller _1 and Viewcontroller_2.

Name: **Viewcontroller_1**
Name: **Viewcontroller_2**
Name **of Segue: g_over**
Name **UILabels: g_over_result**

I need find a easy/fast solution to generate a IBACTION/Void  to transfer value of the UILABEL Viewcontroller_1 to UIlabel Viewcontroller_2 (when you open)

Thanks in advance,
Edit.

Answer (score 1):

In ViewController_1 implement de `prepareForSegue` method. And inside that method you can pass any properties to ViewController_2

Check this other post: [How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)