# Pass variables from one ViewController to another in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a calculator class, a first ViewController to insert the values and a second ViewController to show the result of the calculation. Unfortunately I get a error called "Can't unwrap Optional.None" if I click the button. I know it's something wrong with the syntax, but I don't know how to improve it.

The button in the first Viewcontroller is set to "Segue: Show (e.g. Push)" in the storyboard to switch to the secondViewController if he gets tapped.

the calculator class is something like:

```
class Calculator: NSObject {

    func calculate (a:Int,b:Int) -> (Int) {
        var result = a * b
        return (result)
    }
}
```

The Viewcontroller calls the function, inserts a/b and wants to change the label which is located in the secondviewcontroller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func myButtonPressed(sender : AnyObject) {
    showResult()
}

var numberOne = 4
var numberTwo = 7

var myCalc = Calculator()

func showResult () {
    var myResult = myCalc.calculate(numberOne, b: numberTwo)
    println("myResult is \(String(myResult))")
    var myVC = secondViewController()
    myVC.setResultLabel(myResult)
}
```

And here is the code of the secondViewController

```
class secondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var myResultLabel : UILabel = nil

func setResultLabel (resultValue:Int) {
    myResultLabel.text = String(resultValue)
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How are you changing between the `UIViewController`s?

Comment: Thank you guys, I added the information in my first post. I just realized that I had to create an instance of my class, which is now called "myVC". Unfortunately I get another error called "Can't unwrap Optional.None" now.

Comment: In `showResult()` where is the value of `secondViewController` coming from?  Is is a global variable?  It doesn't look like an attribute in your `ViewController` class.  Can you use `println()` (or the debugger) to see it's value before calling `setResultLabel()`?

Comment: create a custom init and pass it in there... ?

Answer (score 17):

In Swift, everything is public by default.
Define your variables outside the classes:

```
import UIKit

var placesArray: NSMutableArray!

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
//
..
//
}
```

and then access it

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
//
placesArray = [1, 2, 3]
//
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was going crazy to pass the string from NSViewController to NSView of Popover and your solution saved me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the `FirstViewController` has no reference to the instance of `SecondViewController`. Because of this, this line:

```
secondViewController.setResultLabel(myResult)
```

does nothing (except probably causing the `Can't unwrap Optional.None` error). There are a few ways to solve this problem. If you are using storyboard segues you can use the `-prepareForSegue` method of `UIViewController`. Here is an example:

In FirstViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!,sender: AnyObject!){         
  //make sure that the segue is going to secondViewController
  if segue.destinationViewController is secondViewController{
    // now set a var that points to that new viewcontroller so you can call the method correctly
    let nextController = (segue.destinationViewController as! secondViewController)
    nextController.setResultLabel((String(myResult)))
  }
}
```

Note: this code will not run as is because the function has no access to the result variable. you'll have to figure that out yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is, you are trying to set the UI component (here, its the label : myResultLabel)

When  segue is fired from first view controller, the second view has not yet been initialized. In other words, the UI object "myResultLabel" is still nil.

To solve this, you will need to create a local string variable in second controller. Now, set that string to what you are trying to display, and finally, set the actual label in "viewDidLoad()" of the second controller.

Best Regards,
Gopal Nair.