# Pass data through segue

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, detailview

I'm doing simple iOS application with tableview controller and detailView. All I want is to pass data through segue.

[image: this is how it looks like]

this is how it looks.

All I want is that u click on "Markíza" it will open URL video number 1 and if u click on "TV JOJ" it will open URL video number 2 in player.

My tableview cells:

```
    struct Program {
        let category : String
        let name : String
    }


   var programy = [Program]()
        self.programy = [Program(category: "Slovenské", name: "Markíza"),
                         Program(category: "Slovenské", name: "TV JOJ")]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass variables from one ViewController to another in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044108/pass-variables-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-in-swift)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Swift works exactly the same way as Obj-C but is reworked in the new language. I don't have a lot of information from your post but let's give a name to each TableViewController to help with my explanation.

**HomeTableViewController** (this is the screenshot you have above)

**PlayerTableViewController** (this is the player screen you want to travel to)

With that said, in PlayerTableViewController you need to have a variable that will store the passed data. Just under your class declaration have something like this (if you intend to store the struct as a single object rather than the array:

```
class PlayerTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var programVar : Program?

    //the rest of the class methods....
```

After that there are two ways you can send data to the new TableViewController.

**1) Using prepareForSegue**

At the bottom of HomeTableViewController you will use the prepareForSegue methods to pass the data. Here is an example of the code you'll use:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    // Create a variable that you want to send
    var newProgramVar = Program(category: "Some", name: "Text")

    // Create a new variable to store the instance of PlayerTableViewController 
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as PlayerTableViewController
    destinationVC.programVar = newProgramVar
    }
}
```

Once PlayerTableViewController has loaded the variable will be already set and usable

**2) Using didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

If specific data needs to be sent based on which cell is selected you can use didSelectRowAtIndexPath. For this to work, you need to give your segue a name in the storyboard view (let me know if you need to know how to do this too).

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Create a variable that you want to send based on the destination view controller 
    // You can get a reference to the data by using indexPath shown below
    let selectedProgram = programy[indexPath.row]

    // Create an instance of PlayerTableViewController and pass the variable
    let destinationVC = PlayerTableViewController()
    destinationVC.programVar = selectedProgram

    // Let's assume that the segue name is called playerSegue
    // This will perform the segue and pre-load the variable for you to use
    destinationVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("playerSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Let me know if you need any other info on this

Comment: sasha. check on my answer. I need to like. If will be clicked on CELL1 it will open link 1, If will be clicked on CELL2 it will open link2

Comment: I tried the 2) approach and I always get an exception telling that "Receiver PlayerTableViewController has no segue with identifier 'playerSegue'". Just calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` works fine, but then no data is transfered to the new view. :[

Comment: @althaus Have you made sure there is a segue named "playerSegue" in your storyboard? This image shows what you should look for. If that fails, send me some screenshots and I'll check it out. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/art/SB_H_set_segue_identifier_2x.png

Comment: @SashaReid I worked around this by moving the logic to @prepareForSegue@, but after working some more with Xcode (new to the stuff), I guess I just had the direction of the segue wrong. The name was definitely ok.

Comment: @althaus @SashaReid isn't better use `indexPathForSelectedRow` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` callback? Example: `destinationVC.programVar = products[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row]` in the `prepareForSegue` method. Let me know if I am wrong (I am new to the stuff too).

Comment: @SashaReid I'm having the same issue as the one althuas mentioned in a previous comment. I'm attempting to do the 2nd method  and am slightly confused. The segue is going from HomeTableVC to PlayerTableVC in the example, so why are we using destinationVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("playerSegue", sender: self) ? Isn't the current VC the one that's performing the segue?

Comment: I think the last line which calls .performSegueWithIdentifier() should be invoked on self instead of destinationVc

Answer (score 57):

**With Swift 3 & 4**

**In The First ViewController (Send The Value)**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "MainToTimer") {
        let vc = segue.destination as! YourViewController
        vc.verificationId = "Your Data"
    }
}
```

**In the second viewController (Catch The Value)**

```
var verificationId = String()
```

Comment: var var_name = String() - use this in the second viewcontroller to catch the value

Answer (score 6):

If you have no need to discern the action by the identifier but only by the target class...

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? YourViewController {
        vc.var_name = "Your Data"
    }
}
```