# Receiver ... has no segue with identifier error

Tags: ios, swift, segue

The code in question:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    var card: String

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView){
        card = self.filtered[indexPath.row]
    }

    else{
        card = self.array[indexPath.row]
    }



    let destinationVC = SearchViewController()
    destinationVC.searchString = card
    destinationVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("ResultSegue", sender: self)

}
```

I'm trying to pass a string to another view when a cell in my table is selected. In the storyboard I named the segue identifier 'ResultSegue'.

What happens when I run my app is when I click a cell it loads the next view, without the variable I'm sending being updated,  then if I go back and click on a new cell the app will crash and give me the titled warning.

I've tried running clean, and resetting the simulator as other threads have suggested, but nothing changes.

Comment: Did you mean to implement didSelectRow, not didDeselectRow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue here is a SO question that i think can help you! show's you how to pass the data. I also agree with @rdelmar , this is in the wrong function.

Comment: @Jay Yeah, I fixed the function to the right one. I used to link you posted to get the code I have now, someone in the comments had the same problem I'm having, but they didn't specify how they resolved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a the string in `prepareForSegue` function rather than `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function.

Instead of using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as below:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ResultSegue" {

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            var card: String
            if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView) {
                card = self.filtered[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                card = self.array[indexPath.row]
            }
            (segue.destinationViewController as SearchViewController).searchString = card
        }
    }
}
```