# Remove map pins with button, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, locationmanager

I am developing a small map application and I wish to have a button which removes all pins (memories) dropped to the map.

I have this code so far for managing location:

```
// Location function
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.004, longitudeDelta: 0.004))
    self.placesMap?.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let locationDictionary:[String:Double] = ["latitude":center.latitude,"longitude":center.longitude]
    var locationArray = [[String:Double]]()
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("locationArray") != nil {
        locationArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("locationArray") as! [[String:Double]]
    }
    locationArray.append(locationDictionary)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(locationArray, forKey: "locationArray")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Error code: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Here is the button to drop a pin:

```
@IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.placesMap.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.placesMap.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    self.placesMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Here is outlet / action to reset the pins:

```
@IBAction func resetMemories(sender: AnyObject) {
    func removeStoredLocations(){
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("locationArray")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        placesMap.removeAnnotations(placesMap.annotations)
    }
}
```

When I press the button currently no error occours, but the pins still remain on the map :(

Answer (score 2):

In your `resetMemories` `IBAction` you created a nested function `removeStoredLocations`. Then you never call that nested function, so the code never gets executed. I would suggest getting rid of the nested function:

```
@IBAction func resetMemories(sender: AnyObject) 
{          
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("locationArray")
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
  let annotationsToRemove = placesMap.annotations.filter 
  { 
    $0 !==  placesMap.userLocation 
  }
  placesMap.removeAnnotations( annotationsToRemove )
}
```

Or, if you really want a nested function, you have to call it:

```
@IBAction func resetMemories(sender: AnyObject) 
{
  //Define our local function removeStoredLocations().
  func removeStoredLocations()    
  {          
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("locationArray")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    let annotationsToRemove = placesMap.annotations.filter 
    { 
      $0 !==  placesMap.userLocation 
    }
    placesMap.removeAnnotations( annotationsToRemove )
  }

  //Now that we've defined our local function, call it.
  removeStoredLocations()
}
```

### EDIT:

Jthomps is right. You should use his code that does not remove the annotation for the user location. I am editing my code above to incorporate his.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get the same error as I get with Jthomps answer, it is because the button is present on a new scene I think. Have you got any other suggestions to help get this working?

Comment: "...it is because the button is present on a new scene I think." Huh? You think it's on a new scene, or you think that's why you're having problems? You need to edit your question and provide a LOT more information if we are going to have any chance of helping you. As it is I'm voting to put your question on hold.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the nested function that you had within the outlet. That's why it was never getting called in the first place.

Try changing to this code snippet :

```
@IBAction func resetMemories(sender: AnyObject) {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("locationArray")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        let annotationsToRemove = placesMap.annotations.filter { $0 !== placesMap.userLocation }
        placesMap.removeAnnotations(annotationsToRemove)
}
```

Comment: Good point about not removing the user location annotation. (Voted.)

Comment: Note that the OP was using a nested function that he never called. It's important to point that out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this but now I get an error (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION) on the "let annotation" line when the button is pressed :(

Comment: All I can see is the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error message on that line?

Comment: There should be some output in the console that would describe the error a little more.

Comment: Yes sorry, my mistake. In the console it states "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Before you clicked the button, were there annotations populated on the map?

Comment: Yes there were, although I noticed when implementing your code the previously existing ones were erased even before pressing the button

Comment: Are you calling resetMemories anywhere else in the code?

Change the signature of the method to : 

`@IBAction func resetMemories(sender: UIButton)`

As only a button should be calling this function (from what I understand of your desired functionality)

Comment: No I am not, I changed the signature of the method but still the same error persists. I have the reset button on a new scene which is presented modally. They are members of the same class though, but could it be because of this?

Comment: I think that's why you're getting this error. Try running it within the same scene.

Comment: Is there any way to get this to function via the new scene? I dont have space to put a button on the same scene :( Just dragged the button to the same scene and tried, no error but still no pins are removed

Comment: You would have to pass the map as a variable into the new scene in order for this to work.

I would also make sure that you're not accidentally repopulating the map from  an array after clicking the reset button.

Comment: Could you post an example of how to do this? I am new to Swift so it is hard for me to understand. Thanks for all your help so far though

Comment: Take a look at this link on how to pass data into a segue. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue