# SearchController issues in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, search, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to create a search bar that appears on top of the nav bar when you click on "Search" (which is also in the nav bar). Clicking on a search result will take you to a Detail page where the Search Bar will disappear. When you click to go back to the Home VC, the search bar reappears. Thought it would be simple but encountering a few issues. This is what I've done so far

To create the search bar when you tap "Search" in the HomeVC I did this:

```
@IBAction func SearchAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.navigationController?.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**1st issue**, when you go to the Detail page, it search bar doesn't disappear.

**Solution**: In PrepareForSegue, I added

```
self.searchController.searchBar.removeFromSuperview()
```

and replaced the unwindSegue with a delegate so that when the user goes back to Home VC from Detail page, the search bar is added back in. The HomeVC performs the following:

```
func didDismissDetail() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    if searchController.active == true {
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    }
}
```

**2nd issue**: There's a bug in the scenario where you search, tap to go to the Detail page, go back to Home VC, tap Cancel to close the Search controller. When you click on Search button in the nav bar again, nothing happens. I get this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller .'
**Solution**: I added this

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.searchController.searchBar.removeFromSuperview()        
}
```

This works however, there is no animation when the view is removed. Sorry, I know it's a little long winded - my question is:

1. Is there a better way to create this user experience?
2. If not, how can you animate the removal of the search bar when the user taps on Cancel

   Here are some images:

[image: Home Screen][image: After clicking "Search"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `self.searchController.searchBar.removeFromSuperview()` you should use:

```
navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`
```

to dismiss the view. Also, you should give your segue an identifier and check for it in `prepareForSegue`. You implementation may look something like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if segue.identifier == "ToDetail" {
      let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
      navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
     //Pass Info to Detail View
   }
}
```

and then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` just perform your segue with `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   performSegueWithIdentifier("ToDetail", sender: self)
}
```

To allow the searchBar to reappear you can set up a boolean variable called `searchBarShouldBeOpen` on the main view controller. In your `SearchAction` function set this value to true, and then in `viewWillAppear` use an if statement with `searchBarShouldBeOpen` to decide whether to run `SearchAction`. Also, consider making `SearchAction` a regular function and moving everything but the last line shown in your example to `viewDidLoad`. Lastly, implement `UISearchBarDelegate` for your Main View Controller and override `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` and inside it set `searchBarShouldBeOpen` to false. Your Main View Controller would look something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 //...Your Variables

 var searchBarShouldBeOpen: Bool = false

 let searchBarKey = "SearchBarText"

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Search", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.showSearchBar))
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if searchBarShouldBeOpen {
       navigationController?.presentViewController(searchController, animated: false, completion: nil)
       searchBarShouldBeOpen = true
       if let previousText = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(searchBarKey) {
          searchController.searchBar.text = previousText
       }
    }  
  }

  func showSearchBar() {
    navigationController?.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     searchBarShouldBeOpen = true
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ToDetail" {
      let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
      if searchController.searchBar.text != "" { 
         NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(searchController.searchBar.text, forKey: searchBarKey)
      }
       //Pass Info
    }
  }
  //Your functions...
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
   func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
     searchBarShouldBeOpen = false
  }
}
```

In your Detail View Controller add this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Edits:**

1. Changed `viewWillAppear` to manually present the `UISearchBar` without animation rather than using `showSearchBar` so that it would not animate every time.
2. Added missing call to `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`
3. Moved the dismissal of the `UISearchBar` to the `viewWillAppear` of the detail view Controller so the search doesn't go away before the segue.
4. Persisted the `UISearchBar`'s text using `NSUserDefaults` (in `prepareForSegue`) so that way it could be loaded in the `viewWillAppear` of the Main View Controller to set the search to what it previously was.
5. Added the `searchBarKey` constant to use as the key for the `UISearchBar` text persistence, so a "Magic String" would not be used to set and access the saved text.

**Note:** You should really consider using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to perform the segue.

**Other Option:** If you want the `UISearchBar` to animate out simultaneously with the transitioning of the Main View Controller to the Detail View Controller, you can use a custom segue (this will make the animation a bit smoother). I have made a custom segue example that creates this effect. Note that you will have to change the segue between the view controllers in Interface Builder to have kind "Custom" and be the following subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue`.

```
class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

   override func perform() {
      let pushOperation = NSBlockOperation()
      pushOperation.addExecutionBlock {
         self.sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: true)
      }
      pushOperation.addExecutionBlock {
        self.sourceViewController.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
      }
      pushOperation.queuePriority = .Normal
      pushOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated
      let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
      operationQueue.addOperation(pushOperation)

   }

}
```

You can read more about the code in the custom segue here at the following links:

1. Custom Segues: http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/
2. NSOperation: http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/

Hope this helps! If you need elaboration just ask! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response Ike10. I tried it but the issue with dismiss is that it deactivates the search controller so when you go back to the Home VC from Detail, the search bar doesn't appear again. 

If you add a present VC to the delegate method when it lands on Home VC, there's no way to differentiate if the search controller was active beforehand

Comment: Awesome @Ike10! Yeah this would work. I've implemented this and ran into two further minor issues:
1) When you go from HomeVC to Detail, you see it go from the search results back to the original list before segueing into Detail. FYI I didn't use didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I used 'let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow' in the cellForRowAtIndexPath instead. Should be the same

Comment: 2) When you go back to the search results from Detail, it always get animated. You should just see the search results (the last page you saw). I created a 2nd method with animation for dismiss off and ask viewWillAppear to call this instead if searchBarShouldBeOpen = true. This didn't work and don't know why.

Comment: @Danny See my edits for a possible solution to your issues.

Comment: @Danny added something for a cleaner transition from HomeVC to DetailVC

Comment: Thanks for the advice on this. I can't seem to get it working on mine and not sure why. Think I'm just going to keep my existing solution for now. Also, why is it better to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath rather than just tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow in the PrepareForSegue?

Comment: @Danny , which part is not working? And `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `performSegueWithIdentifier` is better because `indexPathForSelectedRow`  in `prepareForSegue` because `prepareForSegue` is called at every segue so the code becomes less efficient as well as the fact that `indexPathForSelectedRow` returns an optional which creates the need to create an unnecessary if let binding to unwrap it. (It is generally a good idea to make code a clean and concise as possible for maintainability reasons).

Comment: very good point! Also I got it working now! What would the code in prepareForSegue look like for passing the data to the Detail VC?

Comment: @Danny I'm glad you got it working! Check out this question's answer for a good explanation of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue

Answer (score 0):

For issue #1, instead of `self.searchController.searchBar.removeFromSuperview()`, you could do `self.searchController.isActive = false` in `prepare(for:sender:)`. That will deactive the search bar when you unwind.