# How to pass values by segue through UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swift3

I have the next structure:

[image]

So, how you can see, I apply segue from the left top controller to GalleryViewController and want to pass some values through the segue, for that I do:

```
if segue.identifier == "goToGalleryVCFromRestaurant" {
   let galleryViewController = segue.destination as! GalleryViewController
   galleryViewController.photos = self.photos
}
```

but because of my GalleryViewController is embedded in UINavController this part will never be executed `let galleryViewController = segue.destination as! GalleryViewController`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Best way would be to include the parent View Controller inside Navigation Controller.

Comment: @Mr.Bista I already, but I do not see navbar inside of my GalleryVC

Comment: This question has already been asked and answeard here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if let destinationNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {

  if  let galleryViewController = destinationNavigationController.topViewController as? GalleryViewController {

    galleryViewController.photos = self.photos
   }
}
```

Comment: but I cannot return back from there =/ There is no "< Back" button =/

Comment: yes. you can't. you have to add left bar button item with image < and add action on that and on click that button dismiss the controller.

Comment: you can't do without this. you have to build mechanism yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a back button when you're done then your structure is wrong. You need to place the previous view controller inside a navigation controller, and then just make the segue a push segue. Problem solved with no fuss and no muss.

```
Navigation Controller
       |
       |
       V

first view controller
       |
  (push segue)
       |
       V

second view controller
```

If you do that then will segue directly to your second view controller AND you'll have a back button that will take you back to your first view controller.