# Accessing parent class property from child class in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, inheritance

I have two `ViewController`s. First is the `MoviesVC` which shows the lists of movies. The second is the `BookmarkedVC` which shows the movies which was bookmarked by user.

I have `movies:[Movie]` property in `MoviesVC`. `Movie` class has a `bookmark = false` flag to determine whether movie is bookmarked or not. When user click bookmark button on cell, I update flag to `true`.

Since `BookmarkedVC` is also showing the lists of bookmarked movie, I inherit `BookmarkVC: MoviesVC`.

In `BookmarkedVC` `viewWillAppear()` method, I fetch the bookmarked movies by calling the function below

```
func loadBookmarkedMovie() -> [Movie] {
    let bookmarkedMovies = self.movies.filter { return $0.bookmark == true }
    return bookmarkedMovies
}
```

The problem is `bookmark` of `self.movies` is still `false` although they were bookmarked.

To make sure, I call `loadBookmarkedMovie()` in `MoviesVC` after I had bookmarked some movies and it actually return the bookmarked movies but in `BookmarkedVC` it `return nil`

Comment: Have you confirmed that the bookmark property is actually getting changed in your MoviesVC when you interacts with the cell?

Comment: Can i  assume that `movies` is initialized when it was declared ?

Comment: yeah the property is changed. I check it by calling filter method on array in `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: @Roy movies is declared as ? and download movies json from server.

Comment: Have a look at: [Apple Developer Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html)

Comment: Are you sure it makes to have the `favourite` property reside in the `Movie` objects? For example, what if you eventually introduce multiple users? If a movie is marked favourite, who's favourite is it?

Answer (score 0):

As a result of [**Inheritance**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) you only can get properties ( `functions` and `variables` ) of **Super Class** .

So If you inherit `MoviesVC` . .

1. Now `BookmarkVC` has `movies:[Movie]` (Lets assume `movies` is initialized when it was declared ) .
2. All `bookmark == false` (By default `false` as you didn't update bookmark yet in `BookmarkVC` )

So  . . `func loadBookmarkedMovie()`  will definitely  return `nil` . To pass data from `MoviesVC` to `BookmarkedVC` all you need to use [Segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue) or [Delegate](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/pass-data-with-delegation-in-swift-86f6bc5d0894) .