# How to pass data between two screens while both are elements in NavigationController in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a set of storyboards under the `UINavigation Controller`. One of these screens contains a table view and I need to send the data of the clicked row to the next screen. I am aware that doing so would require me to use segue. But then how do I get the `Navigation Bar` and the `Navigation Button`

For better understanding I have uploaded the screen shot of my first screen. Clicking on the detail button is going to send the challenge object to next screen. However, I am looking forward to having the same navigation bar on the top of the next scree. Any idea how can I accomplish such objective?

Currently if I press on details `button`, I'll get the details of that challenge in the terminal.

```
@IBAction func CAStartChallenge(_ sender: UIButton) {
           let tag = NSNumber(value: sender.tag) as! Int
           print("challenge name to be printed : \(challengeTableConent[tag].display()) ")
}
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of segue did you use? Maybe you did not use "push"?

Comment: If you used a segue it should show the same navigation bar. Did you used push or show detail?

Comment: Got it. I have to use Push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard you want to drag a segue between the view controllers, like so:

[Storyboard segue dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Emh.png)

Use either `Show` or `Push (deprecated)` options for the segue. Give this segue an appropriate identifier, such as `Details`.

Then in your button function you can add these:

```
@IBAction func CAStartChallenge(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let tag = NSNumber(value: sender.tag) as! Int
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Details", sender: challengeTableConent[tag])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Details",
        let destination = segue.destination as? DestinationViewController,
        let model = sender as? ChallengeTableContentType {

        // pass through model to destination view controller
        destination.model = model
    }
}
```

You can then configure the destination view controller using its specific model when it appears.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**

Passing data through screens using segues is simple. Just check this answer

[Pass data through segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue)

It will explain exactly how to do it

**Second**

Check the bug on your button I think you mean "Details"

**Third**

Check the type of segue, you might not used push or show detail. Also select the details view and make sure that "Simulated Metrics -> Topbar" is set to inferred

Some prints to help

This will ensure that the navigation bar comes from the previous controller

[image: Navigation bar]

This is how your segue should look, do not forget to give an identifier to your segue

[image]