# Passing data between two TableViewControllers in Swift 4 does not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I am trying to get simple `Int64` passed between 2 components in Swift, however, the value is never set.

This is my first tableViewController where I want to pass the data `2` from:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
        if (segue.identifier == "transactionDetailSegue") {
            let transactionDetailViewController = segue.destination as? TransactionDetailTableViewController
            transactionDetailViewController?.id = 2
        }
    }
```

And this is where I want to receive it:

```
import UIKit

class TransactionDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UILabel!

    var id = 0;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dump(id)
    }

}
```

I made sure twice that the segue identifier is the right one, and checked various tutorials, but I am still not sure what goes wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data through segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue)

Comment: Try to add a breakpoint inside the `if` and make sure it got called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `prepareForSegue` is wrong therefore it's never going to be called.

In Swift 3+ the correct signature is

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```

and force unwrap `TransactionDetailTableViewController`

```
let transactionDetailViewController = segue.destination as! TransactionDetailTableViewController
```

If everything is hooked up correctly the code must not crash. If it does it reveals a **design** mistake.

Comment: The declaration of the function was not right in fact, this solved my problem, thanks!