# Refresh data UILabel after updating Json swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel, refresh

Hello I have a problem refreshing the UILabel fields after updating the json. The json file is updated in the API successfully but no the UILabel when I click that to redirect. here is my code

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        //API Update profile and Bearer token
        let token = HPWSLoginManager.shared().saveSuccessResponse.token
        let url = URL(string: "http://51.38.36.76:40/api/v1/updateProfile")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var userNumberTmp: String?
        var userFirstName: String?
        var userLastName: String?
        var userNumber: String?

        // set new values user
        userNumberTmp = self.number.text
        userFirstName = self.firstNameTextfield.text
        userLastName = self.lastNameTextfield.text
        userNumber = userNumberTmp?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

        let json: [String: Any] = ["usernumber": userNumber!,
                                   "firstname": userFirstName!,
                                   "lastname": userLastName!
        ]
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }
            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                print(responseJSON)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "edit Successful!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in

                   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MyInformation", sender: self)

                        // refresh UILabel ???????????????????

                    }

                    alert.addAction(action)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

I redirect the page but I do not know how to refresh the data (in UILabel) when redirecting please help me

Comment: labels inside HPHomeViewController ??

Comment: Just assign the value you want to update in UILabel.

Comment: @Sh_Khan yes that's it

Comment: @sazid008 how? example PS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue

Answer (score -1):

Try this . **You need to pass data to nextViewController as below**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "MyInformation") {
        let vc = segue.destination as! NextViewController
        vc.dataProroprty = "Your Data" // your json data
    }
}
```

**In Next ViewController**

```
var dataProperty = ""

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.lbl.text = dataProperty
    }
```

Comment: please can u explain better?

Comment: what you want exact so i can able explain else this is enough for pass data?

Answer (score -1):

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "edit Successful!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in

                   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MyInformation", sender: self)

                        // refresh UILabel ???????????????????

lblName.text = //Enter your label value here

                    }
```