# (Swift) How to use UISwitch to change var

Tags: ios, swift, var, uiswitch

I have a VPN app I am building, I also have my own DNS servers.

To specify what DNS I want to use I do it in the file `VPNUK1.swift` under `let dns = "1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8"`

I have made a settings page that uses `SettingsView.swift`

I have made a ViewController and added a UISwitch, I have then used `@IBOutlet` to link it to the `SettingsView.swift`

**However** I do not know how to get the UISwitch to change the `let dns = "1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8"` in `VPNUK1.swift` from `SettingsView.swift`

I would like, when the switch is toggled, have it changed to `let dns = "185.136.234.36"`

Comment: You can start changing your declaration from let to var. You can't change you dns object declaring it as a constant.

Comment: Oops my bad, I forgot to make it a var. But how do I change it from a different viewController?

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings view controller use a if / else ui switch to set `UserDefaults.standard.set("1.1.1.1", forKey: "DNS")`

In the vpn view controller: `"dns": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DNS")!`

Answer (score 0):

An `IBOutlet` is a noun. It points to a view/control in your view controller.

An `IBAction` is a verb. It lets you specify code that should be run when a user interacts with a control.

You need to control-drag from your storyboard into the soure for the view controller that contains the switch and create an `IBAction` for the switch, to be invoked on a value changed event.

In your `IBAction` check the state of the sender's isOn property.

You then need a way to communicate the change to your other view controller. To help with that you're going to have to explain how the view controllers relate to each other and how the user gets from one to the other. Are they both on the screen at the same time? Does one view controller present the other one modally?

Comment: The view controllers use a 'PageViewController'