# swift: Transfer data through Tab and Navigation bars

Tags: swift

I want to transfer data from this controller to the other controller (can see in the photo below) how can it be done[image]?

Comment: You have segues so this answer should be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26208831/8447312

Comment: What have you tried? This guide might be useful to look over: https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/