# Click on row and have that row go to another view controller and store some data about that row in a variable?

Tags: swift, xcode

Sorry about the title it's confusing to explain in a few words. I'm still very new to Swift...

I have a table view controller with 5 rows (each represent a YouTube channel), I want to select that row and it store some kind of value based on which row I selected. I need this value for the next screen which is the list of videos based on which row I selected. I'm using Youtube's API so I need to enter in the channel ID in the URL.

This is all I have so far:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToVideoList", sender: self)

}
```

Can I maybe somehow have it grab the cell identifier of the row selected (I can store the channel ID here), then put that identifier in a variable? The next screen would just use that variable as the channel ID.

I know it's a stupid question but I'm still a noob. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue) out.

Comment: Yep looks like this is exactly what I’m looking for. That was quick. I’ll try it out tomorrow. Thank you!