# Pass one variable from one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I new to swift language and know this question is duplicated.I`ve found several similar question and answer, but i could not able to figure out the problem.

I want to pass the value of detectionString variable to ResultViewController from ScanViewController.

ScanViewcontroller as below:

```
import UIkit

class ScanViewController: UIViewController  {

    var detectionString : String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        detectionString = “SomeDetectedString”
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "MySegue") {
            var svc = segue.destinationViewController as ResultViewController;
            svc.detectedString = detectionString
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

The ResultViewController as below:

```
import UIkit

class ResultViewController: UIViewController {

    var detectedString: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
        println(detectedString)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

The println(detectedString) gives me no result. question is that how can get the variable from ScanViewController?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass variables from one ViewController to another in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044108/pass-variables-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound bizarre but there is nothing wrong with your code BUT it does not work as is. I used your code identically and it ignored the segue. Then I embedded `ScanViewController` in a navigation controller in the storyboard. I also put a call to `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MySegue", sender: self)` in the `ScanViewController viewDidLoad` to initiate the segue. Then everything works like a charm. Your prepareForSegue is fine. Yuvrajsinh's suggestion is fine but not necessary (I tried it after changing DetailVC to ResultViewController). Without the navigation controller nothing works. `segue.identifier` is a string and it will work in a straight Swift string comparison.

Here is the code for ScanViewController:

```
import UIkit

class ScanViewController: UIViewController  {

    var detectionString : String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        detectionString = "SomeDetectedString"
        println(detectionString)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MySegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: AnyObject!) {

        if (segue.identifier == "MySegue" || segue.identifier == "SegueFromButton") {
            println("prepareForSegue")
            var svc = segue.destinationViewController as ResultViewController;
            svc.detectedString = detectionString
            println("svc.detectedString: \(svc.detectedString)")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

and for ResultViewController:

```
import UIkit

class ResultViewController: UIViewController {

    var detectedString: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        println("Result Load View")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
        println("detectedString in Result: \(detectedString)")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: ,Thank you for answer, really appreciate your help , it works as you described. beside this , i also tried to get access value of the variable by using appdelegate. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

your `segue.identifier == "MySegue"` is some how not comparing in the way it should.

replace your code with following function and you are done.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: AnyObject!) {
    let segueName: String = segue.identifier!;
    if (segueName == "MySegue") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as DetailVC;
        svc.detectedString = detectionString
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,if i trigger segue by @BIAction , i can get the value from first value.
    `@IBAction func showsecond(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MySegue", sender: nil)

    }`
It crashed whenever i tried to triger segue programatically.

Answer (score 1):

There are three options for you:

1. use `prepareForSegue`method to get the target ViewController and set up the property
2. set up delegate relationship between the two ViewControllers to communicate
3. set up Observer with NSNotificationCenter

Comment: thank you, I tried delegate and it works for me too.