# Pass variable from one ViewController to another

Tags: ios, swift, variables, uiviewcontroller

I have an array: var initialArray. That appends every time the screen is tapped. This is done on ViewController 3

I have a table which displays the array in another view controller: ViewController2.
However the issue is: use of unresolved identifier: initialArray.

How can I get ViewController2 to recall variables from ViewController3?

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


}
//How many rows
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return initialArray
```

//////use of unresolved identifier: initialArray

```
}
//What goes in each cell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    print(indexPath.row)

    cell.textLabel?.text = initialArray[indexPath.row]
```

//////use of unresolved identifier: initialArray

```
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I think your question is duplicated with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390528/pass-one-variable-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-viewcontroller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variables from one ViewController to another in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044108/pass-variables-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-in-swift)

Comment: Each view controller needs its own properties.

Comment: @Lucas where are you declare initialArray . you should declare it ViewController2

Comment: @Lucas or Define your initialArray outside the classes to access publicly

Comment: Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522912/passing-data-back-from-view-controllers-xcode

Comment: If your trying to pass variables from a view controller to a previous view controller you can try an unwind segue, and use prepare for segue, and set up your variables in callback.