# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView which contains five cells. Each cell has a a label and a image. Now using didSelectRowAtIndexPath, when  I click on any cell,  a new view should appear which contains a label and image from the cell clicked. The code is:

```
OpenMessageViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OpenMessageVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

OpenMessageViewController is my new view that would appear on clicking a cell.
I have added a label and image in OpenMessageViewController in storyboard. How do I change the label text and image of OpenMessageViewController to the text and image present in the cell clicked.
Thank You

Comment: What's your actual problem? There's nothing wrong with your code, unless your Storyboard doesn't actually contain a visible UINavigationController.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object

Comment: better you search for How pass Object from One ViewController to another. Because you need to track for index of TableView Cell while navigating through View.

Comment: Have a look at this nice tutorial http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-passing-data/

Comment: if your select the cell,does it want to  go another view? Am i correct?

Comment: And also should it show the details of current View Controller in next view controller?

Comment: Yes..once I select the cell, it should go to new view OpenMessageViewController and the new view should show the details of previous cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't put your code in a Xcode project, but couldn't you do something like this to pass the image and text?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Get the tapped cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the destination VC
UIImageView *myImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:10]; // Set tag 10 to the UIImageView in your cell
UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:20]; // Set tag 20 to the UILabel in your cell
controller.imageView.image = myImageView.image;
controller.theLabel.text = myLabel.text;

// Navigate
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
}
```

**Remember to connect the two ViewControllers in IB.** You then have to have a label called theLabel and a imageView called imageView on the destination ViewController hooked up to an outlet. (Feel free to change the name)

Comment: You may need to do some tweaking to fit my solution to your "controller" reference. Let me know if you have any questions