# Pass data fetched from Cloudkit from one viewcontroller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I have a button that calls this function and also calls performSegueWithIdentifier. Segue occurs before the data is the two query returns data. How do i get round this?

```
-(void)recommendSomeone {
    NSString *currentUserID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"KU",self.liaResponse[@"id"]];
    CKContainer *myContainer  = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
    CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [myContainer publicCloudDatabase];
    CKRecordID *currentUserRecordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:currentUserID];
    CKReference *recordToMatch = [[CKReference alloc] initWithRecordID:currentUserRecordID action:CKReferenceActionNone];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactList CONTAINS %@",recordToMatch];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"knotworkGhostUsers" predicate:predicate];
[publicDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Error handling for failed fetch from public database
        NSLog(@"error querying knotwork users %@", error);
    }
    else {
        // Display the fetched records
        self.randomGhostUser = results[arc4random_uniform([results count])];
        NSLog(@"this is the first name %@", self.randomGhostUser[@"firstname"]);
        NSLog(@"knotwork ghost users for current user data returned ordinary title %@",results);
        NSString* searchQuery = @" ";
        NSString *kuTitle = [self.randomGhostUser[@"title"] lowercaseString];
        NSArray *keyWords = @[@"developer",@"networking",@"sales manager",@"engineer",@"doctor",@"facility manager"];
        for(NSString* keyWord in keyWords){
            NSRange checkResult = [kuTitle rangeOfString:keyWord];
            if(checkResult.location != NSNotFound){
                searchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",searchQuery,@" ",keyWord];
            }
        }

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"allTokens tokenmatches[cdl] %@ AND contactList CONTAINS %@",searchQuery,recordToMatch];
        CKQuery *query2 = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"knotworkGhostUsers" predicate:predicate];
        [publicDatabase performQuery:query2 inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *response, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Error handling for failed fetch from public database
                NSLog(@"error querying knotwork users %@", error);
            }
            else {
                // Display the fetched records
                self.recommendedGhostUser = response;
                NSLog(@"knotwork users data returned after recom %@", self.recommendedGhostUser);
            } 
        }];
    }
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Recommend" sender:nil];

}];
```

}
*emphasized text*

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Normally, you would pass the data in prepareForSegue. Have you tried to implement that? There are hundreds of answers on SO about passing data between controllers, you should do some searching.

Comment: I have tried passing the data to prepareForSegue. But the problem remains that prepareForSegue takes place before the data is fetched

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i have included the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your segue and put it inside your second completion-block.
Because otherwise your completion-block will be called after you already have pushed the segue.

```
[publicDatabase performQuery:query2 inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *response, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Error handling for failed fetch from public database
                NSLog(@"error querying knotwork users %@", error);
            }
            else {
                // Display the fetched records
                self.recommendedGhostUser = response;
                NSLog(@"knotwork users data returned after recom %@", self.recommendedGhostUser);
                //Put it in here
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Recommend" sender:nil];
            } 
        }];
```

Also you could use `prepareForSegue` to pass your value to the second controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Set Segue name from storyboard
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"seguename"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

([Link to segue-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object))

Comment: Thank you. I need to pass the results from the first completion block and response from the second to the view controller I am segueing to. How do i do that? Even though i have passed the two to global variables; the global variables are  empty outside the block