# identify the cell that was clicked in a storyboard application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, storyboard

How to identify the cell that has been clicked. Thereafter, i want to the record stored in that row and navigate and display those values another viewcontroller.

This is a storyboard application that i am using, so can you tell me how to get this done from it.

Before, i used the following method to identify the cell clicked, and then by the use of `indexPath` i am able to get the record that has been selected so i can navigate to the other viewcontroller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

How to do this in a storyboard enviroment. I am using `segue` to navigate.

Comment: I don't believe storyboards can be used for what you want it for, it's not that smart.

Comment: Check out this link..This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `sender` parameter to get the cell, then use a reference to your tableView to get the indexPath. In this example I use self.tableView:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    // Get model object related to index path and pass it to next VC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices really.

1) In storyboard create the segue between the cell and your target view controller. This will automatically cause the segue to  fire when you click the cell.

2) Do what you are doing and call the segue yourself using `performSegueWithIdentifier`. In this case you need to draw the segue in storyboard from the source controller to the target controller.

In both cases you will need to arm the target controller in `prepareForSegue` with the data the target controller is to display. Ideally make your cell have properties which are either indexes into your data model or references to the data they are views for in the table.

In approach 1) the sender will be the cell in `prepareForSegue`. In approach 2) the sender will be whatever you pass in the `info:` parameter.

Comment: But, how can i get the content of that row and pass it to the next viewcontroller ?

Comment: You should add a property to your cell which holds an index to the data or a reference to the data. In `createCellForRowAtIndexPath`, when you create the cell, assign the property. Then in your `prepareForSegue` you can extract it. Simplest property is to assign the indexPath. You can also use `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` in prepareForSegue assuming the row is selected during the push.

Answer (score -1):

```
you have to set a segue from your firstVc to second VC 
Then do
//In your secondVc.h
@property (weak, nonatomic)  UILabel *someLabel;
//In firstViewController.m
in didselectRowAtIndexPath call
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"seguename" sender:nil];
and add this method
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueName"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tablename indexPathForSelectedRow];
   secondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.someLabel = [arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```