# Xcode: How To Access The Instance Of A View Controller Presented Using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When presenting a `UIViewController` using a button on Xcode through code, you usually use

`[self presentViewController:viewControllerInstance animated:YES completion:nil];`

Normally, before presenting the `viewControllerInstance`, I can make changes to that instance like setting some of its properties. However, this time I am using storyboard, and I was wondering how I would access the instance of the view controller being presented if it's not being created in code? I'd like to be able to set some properties of that specific `UIViewController`?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: implement `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7865100/457406

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to thumbs up you or something, but I'm new to Stack Overflow. How do I do that haha

Comment: @MatthiasBauch should post his solution as an answer, not a comment. Then you can upvote it and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your `UIViewController`, add this callback method in .m file:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Segue_Identifier"]) {

        YourViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;

        //dest.yourProperty = ...; set your presenting view controller's properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Stack Overflow is a great community! (I'm a newbie here haha)