# Passing data to destination view controller with performSegue

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

So I know that if there is a segue which is setup and activated through the storyboard, one can use the `prepareForSegue` method to pass data to the destination view controller.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this if one uses the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method? It seems the `prepareForSegue` method is only called if the segue is activated with the storyboard, not with performSegue.

One particular problem is that I can't access the `UIStoryboardSegue` (it is not an argument in `performSegue` as it is in `prepareForSegue`), and therefore can't access the destination VC either.

Comment: Your question appears incorrect - after you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, your view controller will be sent the `prepareForSegue:sender:` message. The `UIStoryboardSegue` object will have a property `destinationViewController` so you can get a reference to the destination view controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

Comment: @RoboticCat ok, yep you are correct, it is calling the `prepareForSegue:sender:` I did the test incorrectly, my bad. Is there a way to delete questions? Since this question is irrelevant now

Comment: @user3809369: A question cannot be deleted once an answer has been written

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here in StackOverflow.
[How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

```
// When any of buttons are pressed, push the next view
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];
}

// This will get called too before the view appears
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {

        // Get destination view
        SecondView *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Get button tag number (or do whatever you need to do here, based on your object
        NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];

        // Pass the information to your destination view
        [vc setSelectedButton:tagIndex];
    }
}
```