# Difference between perform segue with identifier and prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I am very confuse between "**perform segue with identifier**" and "**prepare for segue**"...what these functions do and how they work?

Answer (score 10):

prepareForSegue prepares data to passed between view controllers where as performSegue with identifier actually allows the switch to happen.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSeguePerforming_Protocol/):

- **`Swift2:`** `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:sender:)`
- **`Swift3:`** `performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any?)`

  > Apps typically do not need to trigger segues programmatically. If
  >   needed, you can call this method to trigger a segue for an action that
  >   cannot be expressed in a storyboard file, such as a transition between
  >   scenes in different storyboards.
  >
  > Typically, a segue is triggered by a user action, such as clicking a
  >   button. In Interface Builder, configure an object, such as a control
  >   embedded in the view controller’s view hierarchy, to trigger the
  >   segue.
- **`Swift2:`** `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)`
- **`Swift3:`** `prepare(for: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

  > The default implementation of this method does nothing; you can
  >   override it to pass relevant data to the new view controller or window
  >   controller, based on the context of the segue. The segue object
  >   describes the transition and includes references to both controllers
  >   involved in the segue.
  >
  > Segues can be triggered from multiple sources, so use the information
  >   in the segue and sender parameters to disambiguate between different
  >   logical paths in your app. For example, if the segue originated from a
  >   table view, the sender parameter would identify the cell that the user
  >   clicked. You could use that information to set the data on the
  >   destination view controller.

Answer (score 5):

`performSegueWithIdentifier` just tells the viewController what segue you'd like segue to. You can give your segues names in Interface Builder.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToAnotherViewController" sender:self];
```

You may have a ViewController with several segues or you may have something from the current ViewController the destinationVC "needs to know" when you segue, so [you'd use prepareForSegue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7865100/4475605).

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GoToAnotherViewController"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a TextField in "SecondViewController (YourViewController)" and I want to change frame and Placeholder text. How can I do it? any help please.

Answer (score 4):

[performSegueWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:) as it says, makes a transition from your current `UIViewController` to segue-connected `UIViewController`

[prepareForSegue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:)
let you to do some additional works before transition happens

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference that I didn't see in the answers here and may help to clarify.

The *performSegueWithIdentifier* empowers your code while the *prepareForSegue* empowers the user, needs an user action.

Let's say you have a quiz with some questions and the user has 30 seconds to answer each of them.

When the user clicks one of the answers the *prepareForSegue* will be called. The user is in charge here.

In the other hand, if the user doesn't click anything but the 30 seconds expire, then YOUR CODE should *'perform the segue'* automatically.

That's when you need the *performSegueWithIdentifier* to do the job programatically. Your code is directly in charge here.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perform segue, actually changes the view that the user sees. The perform segue function will call the prepare segue function before it changes the view; so, generally, developers will pass information to the next controller within that function before it segues.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 syntax** is: `performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any?)`. You can do this if you just want to bring the viewController without any *pre*-*configuration* or *conditons*

You can also do `prepare(for: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` which gives *extra* features:

- Passing extra data to the viewController
- doing an if else statement so that based switch between e.g. passing login screen or register screen

basically :  *prepareForSegue prepares data to passed between view controllers where as performSegue actually allows the switch to happen*