# Passing data on segue to view controller (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboard

I would like to pass data to a view controller named "addParty". To illustrate this my app goes from A -> B -> C -> D. A through C are setup pages that take in user information. These pages are followed by D which is "addParty" where I would like all of the data from A through C to be passed.

Below is an example of what I have been doing so far with view controllers A through C.

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
    if (segue.identifier == "Setup1Segue") {


        var DestViewController: addToParty = segue.destinationViewController as! addToParty
            // path the cell's content to your detailViewController
            DestViewController.PartyName = etPartyName.text!
            DestViewController.Address = etAddress.text!
            DestViewController.City = etCity.text!
            DestViewController.State = etState.text!
            DestViewController.Zip = etZip.text!

    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Im having difficulty receiving the data in the last view controller.  @VictorSigler

Comment: What i have above doesn't set the variables i have in "addParty" @VictorSigler

Comment: Are the variables `@IBOutlets`? Please share the code in your `addParty` `UIViewController`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class which is common to all view controllers , and save your details to this common class variables.

1. First create a new swift file called PartyDetails

   ```
   import Foundation

   class PartyDetails {

    class var sharedInstance: PartyDetails {
      struct Static {
       static var instance: PartyDetails?
       static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
     }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
       Static.instance = PartyDetails()
    }

      return Static.instance!
    }

    var partyName: String?
    var address: String?
    var city: String?
    var state: String?
    var zip: Int?
   ```

   }
2. Then in ViewControllers A,B,C put this code

eg:-

```
class A: UIViewController{


 let partyInfo = PartyDetails.sharedInstance

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "Setup1Segue" {
        let jobDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! B

            self.partyInfo.partyName = label1.text // save your info
            self.partyInfo.address = label2.text // save your info

         }
     }

  }
}
```

3. Then In class D use like this,

   ```
   class D: UIViewController {

    var partyInfo = PartyDetails.sharedInstance

     override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()

      myLabel1.text = self.partyInfo.partyName
      myLabel2.text = self.partyInfo.address
      }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You need **override** the ´prepareForSegue´ method in your ViewController.

In your **FirstViewController.swift** defined any action to show the SecondViewController and in this ViewController (SecondViewControler.swift) you need to declare the variables that you will receive the FirstViewController.swift

FirstViewController.swift

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "btnSubmitSencondViewController") {
    var svc = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController;
    svc.dataPassed = fieldA.text
    svc.secondDataPassed = fieldB.text
 }
}
```

Finally! In our second view controller class file (SecondViewController.swift) we need to assign the variables to the display labels when the viewDidLoad is called. This is straight forward, just look for the override func viewDidLoad() and enter the code below.

```
labelA.text = dataPassed
labelB.text = secondDataPassed
```

Comment: `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'dataPassed'`

Answer (score 1):

If the information is very important and you need to make sure that it can be accessed all across the app you can place the variable in the app delegate

first, make custom class like the this

```
import Foundation

class PartyDetails: NSObject
{
    var partyName: String? = nil
    var address: String? = nil
    var city: String? = nil
    var state: String? = nil
    var zip: Int? = nil
}
```

In your app delegate now declare a variable

```
var partyDetails: PartyDetails! = nil

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    loadPartyDetailsOrInitializeHere()
    return true
}
```

Now you can access the same partyDetails object anywhere in your view controller by referencing it with the following code

```
var partyDetails = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! YOUR_APP_DELEGATE_CLASS_HERE).partyDetails
```

You have to replace the YOUR_APP_DELEGATE_CLASS_HERE to whatever your delegate class is.

This method would be better than passing around object with the changes of segues.
Actually I often do things this way and they are working like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for that. I believe this may be the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Haha if you use this methods you could select me as the answer :)