# how do i get different values in another tableview for each row you select in tableview,

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

have 12 category list (rows) in a tableview1..for each category you select i want to display subcategory in another viewcontroller's tableview..how do i make my viewcontroller2's tableview return different number of rows and different cell values based on which row you select in tablevew1 of viewcontroller1...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("show", sender: self)
    }
    if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
    }
    if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2 {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
    }
    if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 3 {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    }
```

i can identify which row is tapped and perform seguewithidentifier to another viewcontroller2 but how do i get different values from viewcontroler 2's tableview(subcategory) for each row tapped in viewcontroller1's tableview

Comment: you need to use segues

Comment: so you mean i need to create 12 viewcontroller and perform segue for 12 rows?

Comment: it would be only one segue

Comment: if you tap on first row, send first object. You need to wrap up the data using NSObject if you have multiple items on a tablecell

Comment: I can t repost the answer. The answer is well explained in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object