# Pass values between the controller

Tags: ios, storyboard, initwithcoder

I use Storyboard create a view controller,but with the code instantiation，then pass the value to the controller.
I know it will be called "`initWithCoder:`", but in the method the property is nil.
**I get the property values form somewhere?**

Comment: Pleas show your code. It isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: access the property in the viewWillAppear: function

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3qdmb6ktuayl13/CoderDemo.zip?dl=0      This is an example of address

Answer (score 0):

*If* you are creating your view controller through a storyboard segue, use the source view controller's `prepareForSegue()` method, as explained in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7865100/433373).

Comment: (...in which case, your question is a duplicate, of course)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3qdmb6ktuayl13/CoderDemo.zip?dl=0      This is an example of address

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have viewControllers: A (root) and B (presenting). You need to use `prepareForSegue` method from A viewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let bView = segue.destinationViewController as? BViewController{
            bView.yourDataProperty = dataItem
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure your sender is presenting `BViewController` in Storyboard. Otherwise this method won't be called

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3qdmb6ktuayl13/CoderDemo.zip?dl=0      This is an example of address