# How to programmatically go back from Detail View Controller to Master View Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, navigationcontroller

I've been having trouble getting data to pass from a detail view controller to the master one. The hierarchy of the interested parts is

```
TabBarController -> Profile View Controller --segue--> Navigation Controller -> Detail View Controller
```

The Detail View Controller contains a UICollectionView of images, each image having a tap gesture recognizer. What I'm trying to do is to tap on one of the images, pass the indexPath.row to the ProfileViewController and GO BACK programmatically.

When I go to the Detail View Controller there is a Back button already there so the idea is: if user presses on "Go Back" button, nothing happens. If user presses on image, the back button is triggered by itself and the image in the Profile changes.

So far I can tap on the images, pass the indexPath.row but I can't manage to go back to the previous View Controller.

I've tried `navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`and `navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`
but both of them don't work (I put them into the tap function for the gesture and nothing happens with regards to the navigationController, the tap function works fine)

When I print the following I get 1 `navigationController.viewControllers.count`

The only thing that I managed to get working is `dismissViewControllerAnimated` however that goes out of the TabBarController to another view that is before that.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE

I figured it out, it had nothing to do with it programatically, the correct answer was to use 
`navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` however my View Hierarchy was wrong

```
TabBarController -> Navigation Controller -> Profile View Controller --segue-> Detail View Controller
```

Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Please make property with strong attribute of NSIndexPath in both view controller `Profile View Controller` and `Detail View Controller`. Also, pass that object’s reference in `prepareForSegue` from view controller named `Profile View Controller`  like code given below :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        Detail_View_Controller *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyIndexPath:self.object_indexPath];
    }
}
```

In Detail_View_Controller, when you tap on back button please update your selected index in the same property with creating one IBAction, which was passed from previous view controller.

I have taken reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object).

Comment: @ korat-prashant I already have something that does this however I would like to use something native for going back without using segue. I've tried unwind segue but there was no action as well.