# How to get Tag of button by clicking from cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I add  `Tag` for the each buttons in cell(button is single), when is built TableView as:

```
[cell.hiddenButtonWithIdCell setTag:(int) self.responseObject[@"results"][indexPath.row][@"id"]]; // Value is 4
```

Where `hiddenButtonWithIdCell` is button name (Outlet property):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *hiddenButtonWithIdCell;
```

**Important:** outlet in the file `cell.h`

At file where I loop table I have (so event action here):

**Important: (Both the methods in the same file)**

```
- (IBAction)openDetailsOfDish:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Click: %@", [sender tag]); // Here I get correct Tag and equal 20
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Full" sender:sender];
}
```

But at:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton*) sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", sender.tag); // Here is wrong tag
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101014/discussion-on-question-by-abamazi-how-to-get-tag-of-button-by-clicking-from-cell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sender.tag is NSInterger so you should log this like that:

```
NSLog(@"MY SENDER TAG %lu", sender.tag);
```

Check here for more info about using button's tag with segue:

[How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)