# Bring "switch" value from a View Controller to another in both ways

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller, uiswitch

How can I bring a variable from a View controller to the back one? (i.e. from B view controller to A view controller?)

I have a switch value that i set on View controller B and I need to access this data also from the back view controller the A.

Comment: -(void) switchChanged:(id)sender{
    UISwitch *switchController = sender;

    
    if (tappulsante == 3){
        
    if  (switchController.on==YES && switchController.tag == 0)  {
        
        
        self.provina = 1;

        NSLog(@"prodottoscelto: %i", provina);
    }                                                                                                                This is the code and I have to bring the variable "provina" to the previous view controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **prepareForSegue** method to pass parameters from one view to another.

Stack overflow already has an answer for this:
[How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)