# Pass a parameter to prepareForSegue from function

Tags: ios

I have to functions, both of them trigger `performSegueWithIdentifier` with the same segue. But depending of which function was called I need to pass different parameters in `prepareForSegue`.

Some thing like

```
func first() {
  // do some stuff
  performSegueWithIdentifier("My segue", sender:AnyObject?)
}

func second() {
  // do some stuff
  performSegueWithIdentifier("My segue", sender:AnyObject?)
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "My segue" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! MyController
        if functionFirstWasCalled {
           destination.property = value
        } else if functionSecondWasCalled {
           destination.property = anotherValue
        }
    }
}
```

Surely, I can do this by setting booleans from second() and first() and then checking them in `prepareForSegue` - but maybe there is some more elegant way to do this ?

Comment: this shud help you http://blog.xebia.com/understanding-the-sender-in-segues-and-use-it-to-pass-on-data-to-another-view-controller/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object

Comment: I saw both materials. I neither dont have object to pass, neither tag.

Comment: you can pass the method name as string object. What else do you need ?

Comment: Thats a good idea, which I didnt think of. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In objective -c you would do:

```
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueNAme" sender:@"firstMethod"];
```

and you can access this message in the prepareForSegue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([sender isEqualToString:@"firstMethod"]) {
        //firstMEthod called the segue
    }
}
```

The swift equivalent I think would be:

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueNAme", sender: "firstMethod")
```

and

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject) {
    if (sender == "firstMethod") {
        //firstMEthod called the segue
    }
}
```

My suggestion would be to instead of sending a plain string , send a dictionary type object that contains the methodName, className and some other params useful for future debugging.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is send a flag by sender attribute, something like this:

```
func first() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("My segue", sender:true)
}

func second() {
   // do some stuff
   performSegueWithIdentifier("My segue", sender:false)
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

  if segue.identifier == "My segue" {
     let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! MyController
     let isFirstFunctionCalled = sender as! Bool //  cast sender to bool
     if isFirstFunctionCalled {
         destination.property = value
     } else {
         destination.property = anotherValue
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: what if the OP has more than two methods ? In that case sending true or false will not work.

Comment: Passing the same type you can simply write `destination.property = sender as! Bool` since you know `sender` is always `Bool`

Comment: If the OP has more than two methods, you've to send a `String` or maybe an `Integer`. Both will work

Comment: @TejaNandamuri could be an enum, string, etc

Answer (score -1):

Simply set parallel properties in this View Controller which you then pass to the destination View Controller based on the function called. i.e:

```
var a = ""
var b = 0

func first() {
  // do some stuff
  a = "first function determined this variable."
  b = 1
  performSegueWithIdentifier("My segue", sender:AnyObject?)
}

func second() {
  // do some stuff
  a = "second function determined this variable."
  b = 182
  performSegueWithIdentifier("My segue", sender:AnyObject?)
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "My segue" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! MyController
        if functionFirstWasCalled {
           destination.property = a
        } else if functionSecondWasCalled {
           destination.property = b
        }
    }
}
```