# Is it possible to transfer data from one TableViewCell to another TableViewCell by using different? segues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

[Transfering data from one TableViewCell to another TableViewCell][1]

I have `CountriesViewController` with `tableView` where is a list of different countries. When I choose a country I want to get `PlacesViewController` with `tableView` which shows different locations in this country. When I choose another country in `CountriesViewController` I want to get another list of locations related to this country.

Is it possible?

[First ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3pRV.jpg)

[Second View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q37px.png)

If somebody had any suggestions and can show some code examples it would be really great!

Thank you guys in-advance!

Comment: you are talking about tableViewCell or after selecting cell you have new view or new tableview cell, show us something more, code or screenshot

Comment: I think you mean, after tapping a tableViewCell, you want to open another tableViewController which will display other cells. A Cell can't display on its own, a cell must live inside a tableVIewController. There is nothing new or unique here, simply do some research on passing data between viewControllers, only difference is detecting which cell was tapped

Comment: so this is a whole tableView not tableView cell, but after selecting cell you can use controller for this tableview and implement method prepareForSegue, there you can pass the data from cell.
In overal i think you should reconsider your idea, if you select something and you want to display data you may not need new tableview but just a viewController

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

Comment: I doubt whether it should be marked a duplicate, because this question is about tableviewcontrollers, and therefore you don't use prepareForSegue but you can use the function that checks which cell is tapped. @Simon McLoughlin

Comment: @Lu_ Maybe I misunderstood something. Just want to clarify one more time. 
I have CountriesViewController with TableView where is a list of different countries. 
When I choose a country I want to get PlacesViewController with tableView  which shows different locations in this country.
When a choose another country in CountriesViewController I want to get another list of locations related to this country.

As I understand it's not possible and I have to use another option.

Comment: prepareForSegue() should suffice just enough. Since the view controllers are on two different place. Use segue to pass datas.

Comment: @Ariel But as I know when I set a segue from a cell to another View Controller I named an identifier. How can I use segue with the same identifier  but with different data?

Comment: yes It is possible.. Only you need to transfer the data from one controller to another.. Make custom cell as you want and then pass the valu from transferred array

Comment: @Eric Could you tell me which function can I use ?

Comment: Use optionals to send the data. In the VC2 add an optional variable called country. Then, you can get the VC2 from VC1 using the segue method prepareForSegue(). Now, get that country optional and set it to the table cell's country name. And, viola. There you go! If you want I can make that an answer with some codes! But, how does VC2 know the list of cities in it? Are you using a predefined city and country list or fetching from the cloud?

Comment: @PavelBogart I am typing my answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to make a **array** of all the data, then when a specific row is tapped, you send the name of that country to the second tableview and in there just filter the **array** based on the country. 
The code beneath just shows you how to check which row is tapped and send that information to the second tableview:

```
var currentCountry : String!

    class View1 : UITableViewController {
        //tableview stuff

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let country = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text //Here I use the title to define which country is clicked
            currentCountry = country
        }
    }


    class View2 : UITableViewController {
        var country = currentCountry
        //more tableview stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I have to implement this chunk of code 
but it's just for transferring data from from ViewController with tableView to another ViewController without tableView.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as!
PlacesViewController
            destinationController.placesImage =
countryImages1[indexPath.row] 
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Which part tells you that the second one should be without table view? It can have a table view - you should use the passed data (for example a country identifier of sorts), and load the places (so the data for the new cells) based on this.

Comment: @Losiowaty Please, could you explain me more detailed what I should do?
I didn't get it yet!

Comment: @PavelBogart post your codes please, if its not licensed. Then we can help you further on.